# Sharepoint Online - Totals do not appear in New Experience view

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am an o365 SP Online newbie so please bear with me as I try and learn this and ask questions.

I swear I saw it before but I had a number field that was defined as a Currency field and Totaled as Sum.

But now, when I go to view the list, I don't see the total above the column's heading.

I am using IE 11 and it does not show in Edge either.

I am viewing as "New Experience" and not Classic.

is this a bug that it won't show in New Experience view?

What am I missing? Thank you

Comment: can you cross check that view and confirm whether the Totals option is applied in that particular column from view settings?

Answer (score 3):

This is not a bug, just not available yet. Hope they come out with it soon.

Source:https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Differences-between-classic-and-new-experiences-for-lists-and-document-libraries-30e1aab0-a5cc-4363-b7f2-09e2ae07d4dc?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: Its amazing that a standard feature like this was not included in the first release so to me it's a bug LOL

Comment: And 1 year later: still not fixed! good job MS.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Office 365 Roadmap](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/microsoft-365/roadmap?ms&filters=&searchterms=total), column totals are still in development and expected in Q1 2019, which is past due date.

[January 2019 SharePoint Modernization News](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-SharePoint-Blog/January-2019-SharePoint-Modernization-News/ba-p/320552) mentions this:

> Coming in February 2019.  Custom views allow you to add calculated
>   fields, such as totals or averages, to the footer of a group or the
>   entire list.  Now, totals will display in the modern view without
>   forcing users back to the classic interface.  Totals will also show in
>   the modern web parts for lists and libraries.

Sadly, as of 2019 April 12, I don't see it yet on any of my tenants.

This is how it is supposed to look:

[image]